# can't compile wxformbuilder (ubuntu 20.04.3)

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

i am trying to install wxformbuilder following the [instructions](https://github.com/wxFormBuilder/wxFormBuilder/blob/master/README.md#ubuntu); i already installed the prequisites, then deleted cmake to install a later version (3.22.2); however, when I try to build i get this:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is at least version "3.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:1025 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:116 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/k-russell-smith/wxFormBuilder/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

i have no idea what's causing this, i already compiled wxwidgets from source a few days ago and have had no problems with it until now

Comment: Have you tried running with `--debug-find`?

Comment: @AlexReinking well, it gave me this: ```CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:116 (find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for wxWidgets.cmake

    /home/k-russell-smith/wxFormBuilder/cmake/modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake

  The file was found at

    /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake

  

  The module is considered not found due to wxWidgets_FOUND being FALSE.
```

Comment: i tried creating a symlink, but it still gives me the error (only with the "considered path" being blank)

Comment: The error message is about not finding wxWidgets library. "I already compiled wxwidgets from source" - Have you **installed** them? If yes, whether have you installed them system wide or into custom installation prefix?

Comment: it's installed system-wide... i used checkinstall and also `make install`